# Unable to configure Lookup Filter

Tags: lookup, lookup-filter

I,ve one Parent object '**Patient**' and Child Object '**Patient** **Services**' and another Parent object '**Job**'.

On **Patient Services** Object one Look up field Named **Patient** related to **Patient object** & another lookup field Named **job** related to **job object**. The Location Field on both **object Patient and Job.**

When adding a **Patient Service** from the **Patient object**; then the Job field lookup should filter based on the **Location** of the Patient.

[image: User-added image]

When I click on **Job lookup field icon**, it allow to show me only record that has location field is equal to  location field of Patient record (Patient 000972) in above image.

Suppose I am  creating a record of **PatientService** from **patient** object related list which is **PatientService1** and it's parent record is **Patient1**
Now when I click on Job field look up icon it allow to show me all related Job Record. **conditon**  Job Record :Location == Patient record's location.

When It show me related job record in look up filter then I can select one of the record from them manually.

[image]

one location field has multiple recrod.

It would show me multiple record as shown in above image then i will select one record manually.

How to implement this Please Suggest

Comment: Create a dependent relationship what you say?

Comment: I'm not getting it how? Can you please elaborate your point.

Comment: Go through this [https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_lookup_filters.htm&language=en](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_lookup_filters.htm&language=en)

Comment: I checked it. It will not allow to show me fields of Look up field patient. By Standard Functionality of look up filter  it is not possible

Comment: When you are creating new lookup then set `Lookup Filter` in 3rd step;

Comment: Yes in look up field their is option to set filter criteria. but I can not set the field of **patient look up field**. We not Not able to compare require field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ;)

1 Create a look up field on parent object let say on `Account` for this object;

2 Again create a new lookup field for the other object child let say for `Contact` for this object; Wile creating this lookup in step 3 of 6;

*Lookup Filter* => **Show Filter Settings** then click `Filter Criteria: Insert Suggested Criteria` here you will see **filters based on the relationships between objects in your organization. Select a filter from the list, then click Insert.**

If this list don't satisfy your requirement then use the form below to create custom relationship;